# Woocommerce quick checkout form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, checkout

I want to add checkout form in product detail page in woocommerce that anyone which is at product page fill the form and place order i want to add a custom quick checkout form on a single product page here is the reference see the image [Quick checkour order form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VIwR.png)

Comment: Done `wc_create_order`Create a new order programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can to create the order programmatically. Use something like below. Please adjust the script according to your need.

$order_args          = array(

```
                  'status'        => '',

                  'customer_id'   => get_current_user_id(),

                  'customer_note' => null,

                  'order_id'      => 0,

                  'created_via'   => '',

                  'parent'        => 0
           );

           $order = wc_create_order( $order_args );

           $order->add_product($postsale_product, $order_qty, $product_args);

           $order->set_address($original_order->get_address('billing'), 'billing');

           $order->set_address($original_order->get_address('shipping'), 'shipping');

           $order->set_total($order_total);

           $order->add_order_note('Upsell order');

           $order->set_payment_method($payment_method);

           $order->calculate_shipping();

           $order->calculate_taxes();

           $order->calculate_totals();
```